# In android studio how do I use mipmap folder assets inside xml layout file

Tags: android, android-layout, android-studio

How do I use an image that is in the mipmap folder as an xml resource, similar to

```
src="@drawable/myimg"
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just use mipmap instead of drawable

```
src="@mipmap/myimg"
```

Answer (score 5):

you should be able to use `@mipmap`. Be aware that mipmap should be only used for the icon launcher. For your app, you should use always `drawable`